# Add items in numpy arrays where each item has an associated "type"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering if it's possible to add `numpy` arrays together item-wise, where each item has a "type" associated with it.

For example, say I have the following 2 arrays:

```
array1 = [[2 'x'] [3 'y'] [4 'z']]  
array2 = [[10 'x'] [6 'z']]
```

And I would like to produce this array:

```
array3 = [[12 'x'] [3 'y'] [10 'z']]
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this using `numpy`? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to write down `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'z'`? Can they not follow from the column/position in the matrix/array?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep track of 'x', 'y' and 'z' and it's not possible to keep track of them based on their position in the array because of the data format I'm dealing with.

Comment: But since you are defining the numpy matrix, why can you not create the data format? There *are* ways to create custom object and store them in a `numpy.array` but then you will have to define all operations manually and you will not get any advantages of using `numpy` over plain old Pyhton.

Comment: Those don't look like arrays.  Except for the missing commas they are more like lists.  Or better yet, dictionaries.  What you are asking is not normal `numpy` behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use numpy directly or make advantage of pandas built-in groupby method.

**Numpy Implementation**

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[2, 'x'], [3, 'y'], [4 ,'z']])
a2 = np.array([[10, 'x'] ,[6 ,'z']])

# Stack the two arrays together
a = np.vstack([a1,a2])

# Define "groups"
grp = np.unique(a[:,1])

# Groupby each group in grp and sum the other column
np.array([[a[a[:,1]==g][:,0].astype(float).sum(), g]  for g in grp])
array([['12.0', 'x'],
       ['3.0', 'y'],
       ['10.0', 'z']], dtype='<U32')
```

**Pandas Implementation**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Convert a into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list('ab'))
# Cast first column type
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int)

# Use groupby sum
df.groupby('b').sum().reset_index()[['a','b']].to_numpy()
array([[12, 'x'],
       [3, 'y'],
       [10, 'z']], dtype=object)
```